# Which type of Projects/Apps are suitable/best to be developed in blockchain/dapp technology?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, dapps

Which kind of Apps are best to be developed on the base of blockchain/dapp/web3 technology. Suggest me please as I am looking for an advice for an academic final year project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I would say games, or possibly anything that can be utilized trading cards, reward systems and/or supply chains

Comment: Thanks dear, can you explain a bit more or examples?

Comment: So for erc721 tokens, there are a lot of examples go to etherscan and see https://etherscan.io/tokens-nft and/or for erc20 tokens.

Simple approaches can involve blockchain gambling, but often times people find exploits in the smart contracts, I wouldn't gamble in a dapp.

There are also exit scams such as https://exitscam.me/, but my favourite application is eth-plot https://github.com/nodesmith/eth-plot.

Comment: All things considered you would build an election dapp (I plan to do this later on, social media dapps (not very useful at the moment, but if you look at facebook which is unethical, maybe we do need decentralization), consider looking at dapp university https://github.com/dappuniversity.